# UK transit visas - single or multiple entry?

Tags: uk, transit-visas

I'm doing a Europe tour with a UK company which leaves from the UK and returns to the UK by coach. I will have to apply for a land UK transit visa (I'm Zimbabwean) but does anyone know if those are multiple entry? If not, what can I do to ensure I am allowed re-entry into the UK on return from my tour?

Comment: What Michael is saying seems spot on, most of these visas do allow you re-entry for a specific period of time. However, I would suggest speaking to the tour company your coach tour is booked with. A fellow South African friend of mine was having visa trouble before his coach tour with Expat Explore, which also began and ended in the UK. He spoke to them and they were super helpful, pointing him in the right direction even though he was travelling on a South African passport (I assume Zimbabwean passports can be equally problematic as ours).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most UK 'Transit Visitor' visas are [multiple entry with a 6 month validity](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/transit-guidance). Single entry transit visas are rare. But you should ensure that you provide your complete itinerary when you apply for the visa.

From the [guidance](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827042/transit-guidance-v4.0ext.pdf) to entry clearance officers:

> You should normally issue a ‘transit visitor’ visa if you are
>   satisfied that the passenger:
>
> - meets all the eligibility requirements of paragraph V7.5 of
>     Appendix V
> - should not be refused under any of the suitability rules
>     of Part V3 of Appendix V
>
> You should issue a **multiple entry** ‘transit visitor’ visa valid for **6
>   months** (long-term ‘transit visitor’ visas are not available). The
>   length of leave for ‘transit visitors’ is 48 hours.
>
> Single entry ‘transit visitor’ visas would be issued on rare occasions
>   for a maximum validity period of 6months, conferring leave to enter
>   for 48 hours, but allowing the applicant to enter the UK only once–for
>   example, the applicant only has limited validity left on their entry
>   clearance for the country of destination.
>
> An example of when it may be appropriate to reduce validity is where
>   evidence of acceptability in the country of destination (outbound or
>   return journey) expires in less than 6 months. Some countries require
>   passports/travel documents to have a minimum validity period remaining
>   before travel.